# how to make Iframe in page only vertical display

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe with width 800px and height 200px. i want it to display a page only in horizontal. means that i has no vertical content.

```
<iframe src="recipelist/" width="800px" height="250px" scrolling="yes" class="iframe-class" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

the content of the iframe is a dyamic generated page (blog posts) with 100% width, which means that it will continue on horizontally when new posts comes in. the height for each item is 200px and i display: inline-block every item so that it lines up horizontally.

to understand better, i want to only display the items in a vertical line only. do i need to code the iframe or the page inside the iframe?

how can i make the parent page show it horizontally? means without vertically scrolling? just show an iframe with max width?

Comment: overflow-x:hidden should do the trick

Comment: sorry. i didn't want it to display vertically. i want it to display horizontally.

Comment: overflow-y:hidden should do the trick ;)
also, take off scrolling="yes".
instead add overflow-x:scroll in css

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/8cTJW/5/

Answer (score 1):

`<iframe src="www.google.com" class="iframe-class" frameborder="1" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

in style

```
.iframe-class {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 height: 600px;  
 width: 200px;
 }
```

Comment: sorry, i typed everything wrong. i wanted to display it horizontally not vertically.. sorry